# How to get access to Icinga on Apache 2.4?

Tags: freebsd, apache-2.4

I am trying to install Icinga on a FreeBSD 9.1 box with Apache 2.4.
I use the Apache config which was provided with the Icinga port.

But when i try to access the web frontend, i get the following error in my log:

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /usr/local/www/icinga/: No matching DirectoryIndex (none) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

I have a DirectoryIndex directive in my httpd.conf, but not in the Icinga config snippet, which uses index.html as an index. The Options directive is `Options None`.

When i try to specify a custom Directory Index in the Icinga config snippet, i get the following error:

> Invalid command 'DirectoryIndex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

So Google tells me that maybe my mod_dir isn't enabled. Well, it is not in the modules list in httpd.conf where i can uncomment the modules to load, but i have a DirectoryIndex directive in my httpd.conf which is accepted by Apache.

So i am struggling to get the Icinga web frontend to work, and i was hoping that anyone can help me.

Comment: can you access the webfrontend when opening it via http://url.tld/index.html ?

Comment: Yes, but my browser tries to download a file called tac.cgi. I think i have to look over my cgi config, but this would be my problem after i configured the DirectoryIndex.

Comment: `apachectl -M` should tell you if mod_dir is loaded. If not, you should load it via httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

The apache24 package on FreeBSD does not ship with the mod_dir. Check if it is present in /usr/local/libexec/apache24, and if not, install apache24 from ports.
Add `LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache24/mod_dir.so` to your httpd.conf.